# Locate element in popup

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

While deleting a user from my list, a JavaScript popup appears that asks to confirm this action, it has two buttons "OK" / "Annuler" :

[image]

How can I locate those buttons using selenium in order to interact with them?

Comment: *How can i locate those buttons ? Any idea ?* No. Please provide code so we can help you.

Comment: Including your code in the page (with both webdriver and html of the webpage) would help clarify what is happening. However, if the pop-up is not attached to the DOM, selenium may be unable to interact with it.

Comment: Exactly,  it's a js alert :( it's not attached to the DOM

Comment: It's rendered by your browser (and thus browser-specific). There's no way to edit it's appearance. It's called an "alert" (JS-function: `alert('Hello world');`)

Comment: thanks a lot ! so i'm blocked here :( there is no solution to confirm my action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution we can use this, it's working for me :

```
String alertmsg = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
System.out.print(alertmsg);
driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); // or .dismiss(); to click "Annuler"
```